# How do I correlate two identically coded variables sent in the response from a Worklight server response string in LoadRunner 12.02?

Tags: correlation, loadrunner

I am trying to create a load test versus one of our apps that is used on web and mobile.  I am trying to access this app from the web.  I login to the website.  Using this login, I click on the web version of the app.  The below response is returned here.

This app is using SiteMinder and Worklight to negotiate with the main site I am coming from.

My question is, how do I correlate a value such as 'SMIDENTITY=' when it is being returned TWICE in the same string?

Here is an example of what is being returned by the server (I have broken up the string so the variables are separated:

> Test4.c(225):
> Cookie:testcookie=oreo;
>
> SMIDENTITY=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;
>
> _ga=GA1.2.653519056.1433336304;
>
> test_pol=UQEpK70TB9Ps6k9Zn0ZxC/WTTWAF7+1iJrMLhMAAA7SYUNDT9zue/krOWPgYi0yqdM6KUELeseH7xg==;
>
> prismdc=prism1;
>
> SMSESSION=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;
>
> SMIDENTITY=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;
>
> LtpaToken2=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;
>
> LtpaToken=EHYGd9YV18oZsd8vSkJGm6EitmZCspgF2RbWMb/kDol6urQ8ZBeespgw8VR0jXPkwKdnAQjJ5x4ZdmTexnZiL3QIVzdH+DwWbTNP4KBAe/cdizYf8/0w05B9N13YX4rT7xl/Y0ZUhZX1brNgM7zP19a4IjL0E0M5uK2qah9ggErQhovcziPkA6Uubd4ne5keV/H/S0ZdaRMSjhXp6njlRtJl6C2U5r91YTXYVnbnl+sgG88g9jnPa6+peg+yi4P9VeoSohydoAIrqBGbpr7yL9ocaO3dL6bq/Ff6WAWZuca1V+7+x4bxtWHQ2CgafibbAkowunOsCyHvCRbv2FH8MQ==;
>
> JSESSIONID=0000QLn5MU6tB5uMM0bXlOC8ZYS:15b4l3mm8;
>
> SITE_ENTRY_JUMPTO=polhome;
>
> scoreboard="";
>
> scoreboardReport="";
>
> WLSESSIONID=0000Xr6ZS67VI4UH-HoycrnVBq1:18lm04lom\r\n

Answer (score 0):

Use the Ordinal (or index) number of the instance of the variable which you need as part of your collection

See training material or online help for correlation functions related to ordinal value

Comment: I appreciate your time, I do, but this is a bad answer.  I looked through the help, looked through google (all tutorials are from older versions and not 100% reliable), and I have asked questions on HP.  I think an answer to this question would help the community a lot, which is why people come here, to see solutions to other people's questions, not stock responses urging people to look at the tutorials.  If the tutorials were sufficient, then nobody would be asking questions.

Comment: And just why is the use of an ORDINAL factually incorrect?  If you have two items with the same left and right boundary and you only need the second instance, why can you not use the ORDinal or the index of the capture to collect the correct instance for your use?  This has been so since LoadRunner version 4.5x.   This is covered in classroom training, the tutorial and in the online help.

Comment: It isn't incorrect, I just don't know how to do it, I will work with it today, post my code, and maybe you can chime in.  Also, could you point me to the correct tutorial and online help?  That would be helpful because I have been through it all.     *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what you're actually trying to do. Do you need only use the most recent? only use the first?

You use a web_reg_save_param_ex to capture all Ordinals of a parameter. It puts it into an array.
You can then do what you want with that array.
You can also use a web_reg_save_param_regexp

I coped the code from the official documentation and put your variable name in there to make it easier for you.

```
web_reg_save_param_ex(
    "ParamName=SMIDENTITY", 
    "LB/IC=SMIDENTITY=",
    "RB/IC=;",
    "Ordinal=all",
LAST);

web_submit_data("...");

/*     Getting individual elements from a parameter array.
    Since the parameter created by web_reg_save_param_ex 
    is called "SMIDENTITY", the number of elements
    is saved in parameter "SMIDENTITY_count".
    The array elements are parameters "SMIDENTITY_1",
    "SMIDENTITY_2", ... "SMIDENTITY_n".
*/

elemCnt = atoi(lr_eval_string("{SMIDENTITY_count}"));

lr_output_message("Number of items found = %d",elemCnt);


for (x=1;x<=elemCnt;x++) {
    sprintf(arrayParamName, "{SMIDENTITY_%d}", x);
    lr_output_message ("%s: %s",
        arrayParamName,
        lr_eval_string(arrayParamName)); 

}
```

Comment: Michael, thank you so much.  Where did you find that official documentation?  I went into the help and the reference and could not find this.

Comment: In Help -> Function reference, then look up web_reg_save_param_ex. You will see there's examples.